# Slackware Upgrade on new release

Tags: slackware

I am about to install Slackware . Likely using Salix however a little concerned getting in st the rear end of the 13.37 cycle .

If I install now and in a month anew release of Slackware occurs will a brand new install be required or is there a similar facility to dist-upgrade?

Should I just use slackel and stay on Slackware current?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating Slackware on a personal desktop machine is pretty harmless in my experience and there's always a step-by-step guide in [UPGRADE.txt](http://slackware.mirrors.tds.net/pub/slackware/slackware-13.37/UPGRADE.TXT). Even if you temporarily break something, you'll learn the Slackware way by fixing it.

(Sidenote: since Slackware-current is not in the "let's call this a tentative beta" stage yet by the latest -current changelog entries, I wouldn't expect a new Slackware before August.)